# AmCharts show all line descriptions

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I'm using amCharts to display a map. After clicking on icon, I want to zoom and display all "description" tags defined in lines. I've added property `map.allowMultipleDescriptionWindows = true;` for displaying more descriptions at once. Then I've added listener to handle click events, but it leaded to looping.

Then I've edited code in zoom event - when I click "3" icon, I get all the line objects and call `map.clickMapObject(line);` but the problem is that the description displays at my cursor position and I need it to be at line position as here:

[image: amCharts example]

Is there any solution to solve this? 
This is how I define lines and the description:

```
map.dataProvider.areas = [
            {
                id: "CZ",
                "title": "Czech republic",
                "lines": [
                    {
                        id: PLarrowId,
                        groupId: groupId,
                        "arc": 0,
                        "selectable": true,
                        "color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
                        "thickness": 2.8,
                        "dashLength": 0,
                        "longitudes": [
                            26.9098,
                            31.8658
                        ],
                        "latitudes": [
                            53.851,
                            55.8603
                        ],
                        "arrow": "start",
                        "arrowSize": 16.8,
                        "description": "<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr></table>",
                        "title": "Table 2"
                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the description windows properties `descriptionWindowLeft` and `descriptionWindowTop` hardcoded. Due to documentation, if these are not set, the description is positioned near the mouse pointer

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapLine#descriptionWindowLeft